# Ошибка при подключении к wifi-сети

Tags: python, ubuntu, wifi

Пытаюсь написать скрипт для подключения к имеющейся Wifi сети. ОС - Ubuntu 14.04, 64-разрядная. Делаю это при помощи модуля [Wifi](https://wifi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scanning.html):

```
from wifi import Cell, Scheme
cell = list(Cell.all('wlan0'))[0]
scheme = Scheme.find('wlan0', 'DIR-320')
scheme.activate()
```

В схеме заданы все необходимые параметры, однако скрипт виснет на методе `scheme.activate()`. Может кто-нибудь знает в чем может быть проблема? Есть ли какие-нибудь другие способы подключения к Wifi-сети с помощью Python?

Comment: https://github.com/rockymeza/wifi/issues/65

Comment: ОС укажите, пожалуйста

Comment: @JK_Action указано в заголовке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Альтернатива DBUS интерфейс NetworkManager, только не используйте [обертку](https://github.com/seveas/python-networkmanager/tree/master/examples) - там баг, я использовал [прямые DBUS вызовы](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/examples/python/dbus).

Comment: В обертке ошибка была исправлена можно юзать.